# Bound convergence radius of power series without explicitely solving recursion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

Let the power series $\sum a_n z^n$ be defined by $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 3$ and $a_n = 3a_{n-1} - 2 a_{n-2}$.

I want to show that the radius of convergence is $\geq 1/4$ without explicitely solving the recursion. Because otherwise it is trival to show that it's $1/2$.

I tried to bound $a_n$ but I don't find anything useful.

Comment: show by induction that $a_n>a_{n-1}>0, a_n < 4^n$ which are fairly immediate (for the second $3\times 4^{n-1}+2\times 4^{n-2}<4^n$ or using $a_k>0$ we get $a_n<3a_{n-1}, n \ge 2$ which gives a better bound $a_n <3^n, n \ge 2$)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $$a_n-a_{n-1}=2(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}).$$ It is pretty hard to resist from solving the recurrence once we have that identity.